# SPFILE cannot be specified for a pluggable database

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I wanted to create a `SPFILE` from an existant `PFILE` but i keep getting the error on SQL-Plus Linux :

> SPFILE cannot be specified for a pluggable database

Am just a beginner i followed these instructions before trying to create the `SPFILE` :

1. Log on as **SYS**.
2. Disconnect from database (using **shutdown**)
3. Create SPFILE from PFILE

This is the command i used to create SPFILE :

```
CREATE SPFILE = '/u01/app/oracle/product/version/db_1/dbs/spfileorclcdb.ora' FROM PFILE = '/u01/app/oracle/product/version/db_1/dbs/init.ora';
```

These are the files present in the directory **dbs** :

[image]

Am just a learning, i don't know if i should delete the default `SPFILE` and then try to create another ?

Comment: You must be connected to the container database (CDB) to create an spfile. A pluggable database (PDB) cannot have its own spfile or pfile. Do not delete or replace the existing spfile for the CDB with a random/custom initialization file, as it will potentially have PDB-specific attributes for all of the pluggable databases in the configuration. The `CREATE SPFILE` command should generally only be used to restore the spfile from a backup pfile which was created using `CREATE PFILE` from the original spfile.

Comment: @pmdba thank you for your help ! and please how to switch to CDB ?

Comment: @Marwane - _"and please how to switch to CDB"_   I see from the name you tried to give your spfile that you are on Linux (you should have stated that explicity).  At a command prompt and logged on as the owner of the oracle installation, execute 'source oraenv', and when prompted, enter the SID of the CDB.  Then simply 'sqlplus / as sysdba'.  But as pmda said, you should be recreating your spfile only under very extreme circumstances.  So I'd ask - why do you want to do this at all?

Comment: @EdStevens Sorry for the late response, am a student and the professor gave us homework, he said to better understand how Oracle work.

Comment: I executed this command : "select name , pdb from v$services order by name;". And the result was showing only "PDA" and not a single "CDB$ROOT". I don't know why , so i just switched to windows 10  and now it works ! thank you for the help.

Comment: _"And the result was showing only "PDA" and not a single "CDB$ROOT""_  If the only thing it showed was a PD, then were connected to the PD and not the root.  If it was "correct" when you "switched to windows" then you were doing something else different.  Exactly what do you mean by "switched to windows", if your db is  is on linux (as it appears but you still haven't confirmed)?

Comment: _"I don't know why , so i just switched to windows 10 and now it works ! thank you for the help."_   So what have you actually "learn(ed) about oracle", as your professor wanted?

Comment: @EdStevens Am sorry for this late response, it's because of school. "Exactly what do you mean by "switched to windows".", Sorry i should of clarified that i was using a Linux virtual machine to run oracle, it's name is "Oracle DB Devoloper VM", it's released by oracle and already have the oracle databse installed in it with connection adapters. What i ment with "switching to windows " is is that i have a windows VM with oracle DB, the reason why (i think) the linux oracle didn't work because it was just for testing, but it still had the pluggable database and i used it to for small c# apps.